# ios - Subtract NSSet from other NSSet

Tags: ios, nspredicate, nsset

I have two `NSSet`s. One contains all UserKeys and other contains online user keys. I want to show in two sections this values. Section 1- online users and section2 - other users

I did this using predicate like below.

```
NSSet *nsset1 = [NSSet setWithArray:attendeesService.arrof_attendeeList]; //this are all users
nsset2 = [NSSet setWithArray:tempArray]; // temparray contains all online users.
NSSet *nsset2_ids = [nsset2 valueForKey:@"UserProfileKEY"]; 
nsset1_minus_nsset2 = [nsset1 filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT UserProfileKEY IN %@",nsset2_ids]];
```

It works fine. But All users are about 3000+ and online may be 200+ at a time. So it is taking a lot of time. It takes 1 min for 4-5 online users. So for 200+ online users will take more time. Is there a faster solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `minusSet` method?

Comment: see my answer. It filter one array to another array object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your First Array is `FirstMakes` declaration is :

```
NSArray *FirstMakes = @[@"Mercedes-Benz", @"BMW", @"Porsche",
                         @"Opel", @"Volkswagen", @"Audi"];
```

Your second Array is `SecondMakes` declaration is :

```
NSArray *SecondMakes = @[@"Mercedes-Benz", @"Porsche",
                          @"Volkswagen"];

Filter `FirstMakes` to `SecondMakes`

NSPredicate *beforeL = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:
                            ^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings)
                             {

                                 if ([SecondMakes containsObject:evaluatedObject])
                                 {
                                     return NO;
                                 }
                                 else{
                                     return YES;
                                 }

                            }];
    NSArray *makesBeforeL = [FirstMakes
                             filteredArrayUsingPredicate:beforeL];

    NSLog(@"%@", makesBeforeL);
```

Your **OUTPUT** is :

[image]

Comment: Hi, I did it, I extracted all keys from both array to get two arrays of keys. Then used above method. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Use the [`minusSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableSet/minusSet:) from [`NSMutableSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/index.html)

`minusSet`:
Removes each object in another given set from the receiving set, if present.

```
NSMutableSet *nsset1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray: attendeesService.arrof_attendeeList];
NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithArray: tempArray];
[nsset1 minusSet: set2];
NSArray *nsset1_minus_nsset2 = [nsset1 allObjects];
```

Comment: testing with 4-5 online users shouldn't make a big difference, but when you have more connected users, minusSet should be faster than the predicate. (but I have never tried to compare)

Answer (score 1):

Set creation is expensive — `NSSet` has to go through a list of objects, one at a time, asking them to compute their hash and then inserting them into buckets, which require at least some dynamic allocation.

Therefore, if possible don't recreate `nsset1` and `nsset2` every time you run this test. Keep them as sets at runtime, even if that means going to and from an array to store to disk.

`valueForKey:` on a set is also a set creation task. Try not to do that. At the very least switch to `nsset2_ids = [NSSet setWithArray:[tempArray valueForKey:@"UserProfileKEY"]];` to create only one set rather than two.

Use `minusSet` on `NSMutableSet` as per gabbler to prevent the cost of parsing and applying a freeform predicate.

If possible have the two sets contain the same kind of object and implement `isEqual:` and `hash` correctly so that no conversion (which you've achieved via `valueForKey:`) is required in the first place.

Comment: OP accepted the answer from kirit.  But his answer was about NSArray not NSSet.  So, did OP get confused?

Comment: I dint use Nsset. I got all UserProfileKEY in an array. Then used Kirit answer. Still if any other solution on all dictionaries would be helpful. In main nsset dictionaries all key-value pairs like UserProfileKEY, name, address etc. But second NSSet contains on one key-value i.e UserProfileKey.

Comment: Working with arrays means linear searches. Suppose 50 people are not in the 3000 and 50 are. Then Foundation will do (50*3000) plus an average of (50*3000*0.5) = 225,000 comparisons. If sets were used it would be a huge number fewer, probably at least three orders of magnitude. You just need to be smart enough not to recreate the three sets every time you want them (though that'll still end up being faster as your quantities grow because it's O(n log n) whereas array v array is O(n^2); if the sets didn't need to be built it'd be just O(log n))